# Python Requests Deployment

Tags: python, django, permissions, python-requests, apache2

In on of my Django view´s I am making a request to another webserver via requests, this code works perfect when I run the code with the development server. It looks like that:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://www.example.org')
return r.text
```

But when I Deploy this an apaches www-data user is running it it throws this error:

```
ConnectionError
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.example.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded 
with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x7f23e917ba58>:Failed to establish a new connection:[Errno -2] 
Name or Service not known'))
```

But I can run the code as root user from a seperate script on the Deployment server without a problem this is why i think it is a permission problem. But i have no Idea how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have DNS resolution troubles. This usually not related to user permissions.

Comment: @ Klaus D. No I Tried typing the ip and it didnt work :(